# Carousel created using vue not rotating as it should

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a carousel that I found that was created using vanilla javascript and html.  I tried converting it to Vue but am having some issues.  It is supposed to dynamically pull from a SharePoint list.  In the code and pen below, I use an array of objects to simulate a SharePoint list. Instead of it rotating, all the images are listed vertically on top of each other.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#carouselApp',
  data: function() {
    return {
      images: [{
          src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533048324814-79b0a31982f1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60',
          text: 'Tech trends',
          num: 0
        },
        {
          src: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/rainbow-butterfly-colorful-wings-colored-all-colors-vibgyor-very-attractive-placed-black-white-30774133.jpg',
          text: 'Tech Spot',
          num: 1
        },
        {
          src: 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/color-butterfly-isolated-on-white-260nw-570560110.jpg',
          text: 'Tech Idea',
          num: 2

        },
        {
          src: 'http://static.nautil.us/16630_c2e2a6521fbf5aab3693d9dd7ca9cb1e.jpg',
          text: 'Yellowy Orange',
          num: 3

        },
        {
          src: 'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2020/01/07/13/monarch-butterfly.jpg?width=1368&height=912&fit=bounds&format=pjpg&auto=webp&quality=70',
          text: 'Tech chip',
          num: 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/_script/vue.js"></script>
  <style>
    .glyphicon {
      color: #ffffff
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp -->
  <div id="carouselApp" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:501px;margin-top:5px">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" v-for="(img, index) in images.length">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" :data-slide-to="index" class="active"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" v-for="(item, index) in images">
          <div class="item active">
            <a href="/News/Pages/Default.aspx"><img v-bind:src="item.src" alt="..." style=" width:100%;height:303px"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              {{item.text}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: probably because theyre all `active`, check `class="item active"`

Answer (score 0):

The way you would handle this in Vue is fundamentally different than how you would handle this in jQuery.

Loosely speaking, Vue would be declarative and jQuery would be imperative. "Thinking in Vue" would have you break this carousel down into components - meaning, you may have a `CarouselContainer` component which lets you specify height/width/what not.. Then you may have a `CarouselSlide` component which lives in the container, and holds the actual image.. it would look something like this:

```
// Carousel.vue
...
<CarouselContainer /* props, etc.. */>
  <CarouselSlide /* ... */>
    <!-- maybe some children -->
  </CarouselSlide>
</CarouselContainer>
...
```

[This article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-design-and-build-a-carousel-feature-in-vuejs-125f690a3a9e/) is a great example of how to build out and structure something like a carousel in Vue. You can [view the repo here](https://github.com/fh48/vue-pwa-carousel) as well..

Now, to elaborate on the code you provided, you could do something rudimentary like this in Vue: (this is just to get an idea across) [CodePen mirror can be found here](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/bGdexxV?editors=1010)

```js
/*Refactored carousel from this site: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_autohttps://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto*/
/*Would prefer the images to come from a list. Will work on that later*/
new Vue({
  el: '#carouselApp',
  methods: {
    browse(direction) {
      if (direction === 'forward') {
        if (this.currentIndex + 1 === this.images.length) {
          this.currentIndex = 0;
        } else {
          this.currentIndex++;
        }
      }
      if (direction === 'backward') {
        if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
          this.currentIndex = this.images.length - 1;
        } else {
          this.currentIndex--;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      currentIndex: 0,
      images: [{
          src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533048324814-79b0a31982f1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=416&h=312&q=60',
          text: 'Tech trends',
          num: 0
        },
        {
          src: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/rainbow-butterfly-colorful-wings-colored-all-colors-vibgyor-very-attractive-placed-black-white-30774133.jpg',
          text: 'Tech Spot',
          num: 1
        },
        {
          src: 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/color-butterfly-isolated-on-white-260nw-570560110.jpg',
          text: 'Tech Idea',
          num: 2

        },
        {
          src: 'http://static.nautil.us/16630_c2e2a6521fbf5aab3693d9dd7ca9cb1e.jpg',
          text: 'Yellowy Orange',
          num: 3

        },
        {
          src: 'https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2020/01/07/13/monarch-butterfly.jpg?width=1368&height=912&fit=bounds&format=pjpg&auto=webp&quality=70',
          text: 'Tech chip',
          num: 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/_script/vue.js"></script>
  <style>
    .glyphicon {
      color: #ffffff
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp -->
  <div id="carouselApp" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:501px;margin-top:5px">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" v-for="(img, index) in images.length">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" :data-slide-to="index" class="active"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" v-for="(item, index) in images">
          <div v-if="currentIndex === index" class="item active">
            <a href="/News/Pages/Default.aspx"><img v-bind:src="item.src" alt="..." style=" width:100%;height:303px"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              {{item.text}}<br/>
              {{currentIndex + 1}} / {{images.length}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a @click="browse('backward')" class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a @click="browse('forward')" class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```